# Why is my Eaton UPS beeping?

Tags: ups

I just received a new Eaton UPS (Eaton 3S 700). I plugged it to a wall socket and connected a small tower server, a switch and a router. They work fine.

**My problem: the UPS is beeping continuously and the light is blinking green.**

The manual has two relevant entries:

[image]

I am not sure what is the difference between "audio alarm beeps" and "audio alarm beeps continuously" (does "continuously" mean *beeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeep* and not continuously means *beep-beep-beep-beep-...* ?). I have the *beep-beep-beep-beep-...* version.

The first case is doubtful: this is a new electrical installation and all these devices were already powered from the outlet before (though a strip and not a UPS), and they worked fine.

The second case is doubtful as well: not only the devices are not particularly power-hungry, but I see in through the monitoring program that

```
root@srv ~# upsc eaton ups.load
14
```

This means a 14% load. The battery is charged at 91%.

While the UPS behaviour does not suggest it, I see that

```
root@srv ~# upsc eaton ups.alarm
Replace battery!
```

I do not know if this is a default setting or there is indeed a problem with the (brand new) battery. The manual says

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I just received a new Eaton UPS (Eaton 3S 700).

Did you connect the battery inside?  All UPS units ship with the battery disconnected for safety in shipping.

Read the Setup Documentation, connect the battery, plug it in and wait an hour or two for the initial charge to happen.

Comment: Ha! Thank you very much. Indeed, I did not plug in the battery (RTFM...) but this is super weird because i) I tested the UPS by unplugging it from the wall and everything was still running, ii) the monitoring software was telling me something about the battery level etc. I opened the battery slot and ... it was plugged in. I unplug and re-plug the battery and now everything is fine. The package was sealed so it may have been a problem at the manufacturer's - I will request a replacement.

Comment: late update: the replacement unit came exactly as the first one (plugged in), I unplugged and plugged it back and it works the same way. I now suspect that there may have been an isolator in the plug but I did not pay attention and it would be super weird to have such a complicated setup instead of just not plugging the cable in. Anyway thanks a lot for the initial information!